# Reusable UITableViewCell with custom logic

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I understand that a custom `UITableViewCell` can be created in storyboards, programmatically or using a nib. I also understand that any logic which is not related to UI should be in a controller to follow the MVC (Model view controller) rule.

In my case I have a `UITableViewCell` which displays user info like a profile picture and username. Tapping the username performs an `IBAction` and takes the user to the appropriate Profile View. I also have a Follow and Unfollow `UIButton` in the cell which performs server API requests. To stick to MVC rules on creation of the cell I add a target to the `IButton`s and handle the `TouchUpInside` event in the containing `UIViewController`.

I would like to reuse this cell throughout the views in my application but without the need to stay creating targets each time.
Also Storyboards do not allow the creation of `UITableViewCells` without having a `UIViewTableViewController` as a container, which is a pain. Could I use mix nibs with the storyboard?

What would be the appropriate way to create the cell and to add the functionality to the UITableViewCell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're in `storyboard/xibs` so you don't need to add `targets` each time in code. You can hook their `IBAction` through `xib`. Then in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method set the tags of button according to `indexPath` of cell.

Alternatively you can create a custom cell class (inherited from `UITableViewCell`) and implement the button actions in that class. Then you can pass the messages to controller through a delegate.

If you want to repeat this cell in different views then your best bet is to create a separate class with separate `xib` rather then in a specific `controller` within a `storyboard`.

Comment: I like the idea of creating a `UITableViewCell` `xib` with it's own class but won't this be going against the rules of MVC? Shouldn't the API calls be in a `controller`?

Comment: Creating cell with seperate xib doesn't viiolate MVC, however, creating a delegate of Cell to pass actions to controller does.

Comment: OK that is clear. So can I just create a Cell with its class (inheriting from `UITableViewCell`) and for example have the Follow/Unfollow API call in there?

Comment: Don't call API functions in cell subclass. It should always be in view controller. if you're implementing follow/unfollow button actions in cell subclass then pass this message to view controller via delegate or notification.

Comment: Although having a delegate of cell is violation of MVC but you'll not have to set targets in each controller which uses that cell.

Comment: I'm not sure I explained this well. I need to reuse the custom cell throughout about 15 different views. I would prefer to only instantiate the cell and have all the functionality ready in it. To explain myself I would like to replicate what a UserControl in C# does i.e. a self sufficient custom control. I guess this is not possible here without breaking the MVC rules?